# Why am I getting a Full exception in a multiprocessing Python application despite removing items from the queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue

I'm working on a Python multiprocessing application where one process (produce) is putting items into a multiprocessing.Queue, and another process (listen) is supposed to take them out. The queue has a maximum size. When the queue is full, produce tries to remove an item from the queue and then put a new one. However, I'm encountering an issue where, even after removing an item from the queue, the attempt to put a new item still results in a Full exception.

Using a `JoinableQueue` and calling `task_done` has not resolved this issue.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Full, Empty

def listen(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            pass

def produce(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    item = "qwerty"
    while True:
        try:
            queue.put_nowait(item)
        except Full:
            try:
                queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass
            try:
                queue.put_nowait(item)
            except Full:
                print("Full")

def run():
    queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=10)
    p1 = mp.Process(target=produce, args=(queue,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=listen, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a potential race condition. We must first understand how a queue is implemented:

A `multiprocessing.Queue` instance is built on top of a `multiprocessing.Pipe` and its `multiprocessing.connection.Connection` instances. Even if you create a queue with unlimited size, the underlying pipe is definitely limited in how much data can be sent through a connection without the data concurrently being read via the other connection. Consequently, when a `put` is done to the queue the item is only appended to an internal `collections.deque`. It's an internal queue thread that has been started to wait for items to be placed on the deque that actually pops the item from the dequeue and sends it to the connection. In that way the thread that issued the original `put` never blocks (assuming the queue has an unlimited size) since once the item is appended to the dequeue nothing further needs to be done by the "putting" thread. However, the internal queue thread that takes these items from the dequeue and sends it to the pipe's connection *will* block if nobody is reading the data via the other connection.

So to be able to get an item from the queue, two things have to happen: Step 1 is appending the item to an internal deque and step 2 is a thread taking the item from the dequeue and sending it to the connection. When a queue has been initialized with a finite size, once the dequeue has that many items on it the queue appears to be full, But before an item can be  gotten from the queue, the queue's internal thread must be given a chance to run and pop off one of the deque's item. If that has not occurred when a `get_nowait` is called, the queue will still be full.

In your `produce` code you are issuing `put_nowait` calls until you get a "full" condition. But all of the items thus put might very well still be sitting on the dequeue since the thread that reads from the dequeue may have not yet been dispatched. Consequently, when you do `get_nowait` call to retrieve an item so as to allow you to put another item, there may be no data that can be received over the receive connection and thus the deque is still at its maximum capacity. So when you then try to `put_nowait` a new message you discover that the queue is still full.

Let's give the thread that is processing messages from the dequeue a chance to do its thing by inserting a call to sleep when a full condition is discovered before we attempt to retrieve an item from the queue. Please read the comments I have added to the following code:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Full, Empty

def listen(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            pass

def produce(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    item = "qwerty"
    while True:
        try:
            queue.put_nowait(item)
        except Full:
            try:
                import time
                # Give the queue's thread a chance to take at least one
                # item from its dequeue and send it through the connection
                time.sleep(.1)
                # If we have slept long enough, then
                # either the listen task has had a chance to get an item from the queue
                # or the next statement will be able to. Either way, the queue should
                # not be full after the following executes. In fact, the
                # queue is probably empty now because listen has had a chance
                # to run and empty the queue:
                queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass
            try:
                queue.put_nowait(item)
            except Full:
                print("Full")

def run():
    queue = mp.Queue(maxsize=10)
    p1 = mp.Process(target=produce, args=(queue,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=listen, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Assuming sleeping for .1 seconds is sufficient to give the queue's internal thread a chance to process its deque, the above code will now run as expected.

**Update**

I have created a `DequeQueue` class based on a `collections.dequeue` instance. It has two `async` methods `get` and `put` that are blocking but allow other coroutines to run.  In this demo the consumer calls `get` approximately every .05 seconds and the producer calls `put` every .01 seconds (100 items are put followed by a special `None` *sentinel* that signals to the consumer that there are no more items to be retrieved and it should therefore terminate). Since items are being put more quickly than they can be gotten, the consumer will not retrieve all 100 items.

```py
from collections import deque
import asyncio

class DequeQueue:
    """A managed queue based on a deque."""

    def __init__(self, maxlen: int):
        self._items = deque(maxlen=maxlen)
        self._queue_not_empty = asyncio.Condition()

    async def put(self, obj):
        """A put implementation that removes the oldest entry if necessary."""
        async with self._queue_not_empty:
            self._items.append(obj)
            self._queue_not_empty.notify()

    async def get(self):
        async with self._queue_not_empty:
            while not self._items:  # deque is empty
                await self._queue_not_empty.wait()
            return self._items.popleft()

async def listen(queue) -> None:
    items = []
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(.05)
        item = await queue.get()
        if item is None:  # sentinel telling us to wrap up
            break
        items.append(item)

    print(items)

async def produce(queue) -> None:
    for i in range(100):
        await asyncio.sleep(.01)
        await queue.put(i)
    await queue.put(None)

async def main():
    queue = DequeQueue(10)
    await asyncio.gather(listen(queue), produce(queue))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```None
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 68, 71, 73, 76, 79, 82, 85, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there any way to solve this problem without using sleep?

Comment: But what are you actually trying to accomplish,?  See [X Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The code you posted seems quite contrived just to demonstrate this race-condition problem.  It seems that you have a queue of limited size, a producer and a consumer of items placed on the queue.  Then if the producer finds the queue full you want it to throw away the oldest item on the queue just so it can put a newer one on the queue. Is that what you really want to do? If so, what is the underlying reason? **Again, what is the actual application trying to do?**

Comment: Thank you for your response and for pointing out the potential X Y Problem. Let me provide more context about the actual application to clarify my intentions.

In my project, which is quite extensive, there are two distinct processes that I cannot change: one process gets data, and the other processes it. We use multiprocessing.Queue to move data between them. Both processes use asyncio, so we have to use put_nowait and get_nowait to add things to the queue and get things out. This is because using the regular put method would block coroutines.

Comment: The scenario where I am encountering the described issue is almost a direct reflection of the simplified example code provided earlier.

And here's a crucial point: when the queue is full, I can't just ignore new updates. The only thing that's acceptable is to ignore the oldest update already in the queue.

Also, using an external queue solution like Redis or another database, or even a file system, isn't suitable for us. The reason is we need to keep the time between receiving and processing data as short as possible.

Comment: and yes that's exactly what I need to do